# Incorrect CPU usage comparing Docker vs OS

Tags: docker

There is an application running in a Docker container. According to Zabbix CPU stats, this application cannot get more than 40% CPU usage in the server (this graph shows 30 servers running with one container each, but should be enough as proof of concept)

[image]

If I read any of the servers CPU usage right now, using `uptime` or `sar`, I can see that the system is using about 25%-30% of available CPU (this system has 4 cores)

[image]

[image]

However, if I run `docker stats` docker believes that the CPU used is much higher (as this is a live streaming goes up and down, but at a glance looks like most of the time is 70%+, something higher than 100%)

[image]

The current hypothesis is that somehow docker thinks that is using much more CPU that is actually available, and it is not allowing the application to use all server resources.

We are not running docker or the containers with any of the CPU limits (that we know of ...)

What can be happening here? How can I make the container use 100% CPU ?

More information `docker info`

```
# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.12.0)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 38
 Server Version: 20.10.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.0-14-amd64
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.828GiB
 Name: MODCDEL76
 ID: 2MHD:MX2B:UIVJ:DRVP:UIYC:735Y:UPI2:5VCE:RASZ:ETTB:KTNZ:5UHI
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```